# FTPClient can't open file, no such file or directory

Tags: java, android, ftp, ftp-client

I've been trying to send a file to an ftp server via an FTPClient but when I get the reply string it says:

> 553 Can't open file: No such file or directory.

Here is the code:

```
try 
{
    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
    client.connect(hostname);
    client.login(username, password);

    client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
    client.changeWorkingDirectory(workingDir);          
    File dir = new File(savePath + fileName);
    FileInputStream fIS = new FileInputStream(dir);

    for(File files : dir.listFiles())
    {
        boolean success = client.storeFile(files.getPath(), fIS);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), client.getReplyString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), files.getPath() + " Stored = " + success, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    fIS.close();
    client.logout();
} 
catch (SocketException e) 
{
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I've been looking all over the internet for answers but nothing has worked.

Comment: Just tried that now, I got "IOException: caught while copying."
Any Ideas?

Comment: The answer was to move the FileInputStream inside the for-loop.
now it sais the file was transferred but it's still not on the FTP server. I don't get it

Comment: My bad, FileZilla is just slow to reload, the files are there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem with help from CoolBeans.

For anyone with similar problem the solution is

1.Change the:

```
client.storeFile(files.getPath(), fIS);
```

to:

```
client.storeFile(files.getName(), fIS);
```

And move the FileInputStream into the for-loop and change it to:

```
new FileInputStream(files);
```